# How do I get rid of the scrollbar without using overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, multiple-columns

I want a header that is 70px and below it, two columns that take up the rest of the screen height, and do not extend past the screen height. The left column is 100% width. The right column is 30% width and is on top of (overlaying) the left column.

My problem here is that `#left` and `#right` have heights that are 100% of the page height + 70px from the header. How do I get rid of those 70px from the height?

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

header{
    height: 70px;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    background: lightyellow;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

#left{
    background: gold;
}

#right{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: tomato;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

https://codepen.io/riyoyukai/pen/MEGaBR

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question here. It sounds like you don't want the 70px above your content, but you have the header element set to a height of 70px with a min-height of 70px. Removing that height and min-height from the CSS gets rid of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell an element to be `height: 100%` it takes the full height of its parent.

In this case, you've set `#wrapper` to `height: 100%`.

Since `#wrapper` is a child of `body`, which also has `height: 100%`, it takes the full viewport height.

But `#wrapper` has a sibling – `header` – with `height: 70px`.

So when you add 70px to 100% you get an overflow (and a vertical scrollbar in this case).

Here's one clean and simple solution:

```
#wrapper{
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

#right{
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrjKOx

Answer (score 2):

you can use `-webkit-scrollbar` to modify, hide or style the scrollbar

if you want to hide all scrollbars you can do this,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
```

if you want to hide scrollbar of a specific element you can do this,

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

> for some reason this method does not work with css class selectors so you'll have to use id to select the element.

you can also modify the scrollbar like,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.6em;
    background: white;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

here's how you hide it

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
}

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body{
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
}

header{
 height: 70px;
 min-height: 70px;
 position: relative;
 background: lightyellow;
}

#wrapper{
 height: 100%;
 background: lightgray;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
}

#left{
 background: gold;
}

#right{
 width: 30%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 background: tomato;
 opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header></header>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
   Vegan blog Truffaut irony deep v Etsy. You probably haven't heard of them Schlitz chambray art party craft beer Echo Park mixtape, deep v fashion axe Wes Anderson twee McSweeney's DIY. Retro twee polaroid 3 wolf moon, Bushwick locavore organic skateboard keffiyeh Kickstarter Williamsburg sustainable Godard sartorial trust fund. Stumptown paleo put a bird on it VHS hella. Put a bird on it mixtape Godard, vegan farm-to-table letterpress chia hella. Meggings DIY freegan normcore gastropub blog. Dreamcatcher wolf kitsch biodiesel lomo jean shorts, pug fap Odd Future craft beer stumptown locavore cornhole put a bird on it salvia.
  </div>
  
  <div id="right">
   Right content
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```